# Non-symbolic derivative at all sample points including boundary points

Tags: matlab, derivative

Suppose I have a vector `t = [0 0.1 0.9 1 1.4]`, and a vector `x  = [1 3 5 2 3]`. How can I compute the derivative of `x` with respect to time that has the same length as the original vectors?

I should not use any symbolic operations. The command `diff(x)./diff(t)` does not produce a vector of the same length. Should I first interpolate the `x(t)` function and then take its derivative?

Comment: the differential can never have the same length unless you define its value at some initial point. Something like dx/dt =  0 at t = 0. Then you can append this initial value at the beginning of `diff(x) ./ diff(t)`

Comment: @ammportal I do not agree with you, see my answer. Do you agree?

Comment: i think i was a little unclear in my comment. The differential will never have the same length with the approach used by the OP, i.e., using `diff(x) ./ diff(t)`. Of-course the method you have described is better suited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Different approaches exist to calculate the derivative at the same points as your initial data:

1. **Finite differences:** Use a central difference scheme at your inner points and a forward/backward scheme at your first/last point

or

2. **Curve fitting:** Fit a curve through your points, calculate the derivative of this fitted function and sample them at the same points as the original data. Typical fitting functions are polynomials or spline functions.

*Note that the curve fitting approach gives better results, but needs more tuning options and is slower (~100x).*

**Demonstration**

As an example, I will calculate the derivative of a sine function:

```
t = 0:0.1:1;
y = sin(t);
```

Its exact derivative is well known:

```
dy_dt_exact = cos(t);
```

The derivative can approximately been calculated as:

1. Finite differences:

   ```
   dy_dt_approx = zeros(size(y));
   dy_dt_approx(1) = (y(2) - y(1))/(t(2) - t(1)); % forward difference
   dy_dt_approx(end) = (y(end) - y(end-1))/(t(end) - t(end-1)); % backward difference
   dy_dt_approx(2:end-1) = (y(3:end) - y(1:end-2))./(t(3:end) - t(1:end-2)); % central difference
   ```

or

2. Polynomial fitting:

   ```
   p = polyfit(t,y,5); % fit fifth order polynomial
   dp = polyder(p); % calculate derivative of polynomial
   ```

The results can be visualised as follows:

```
figure('Name', 'Derivative')
hold on
plot(t, dy_dt_exact, 'DisplayName', 'eyact');
plot(t, dy_dt_approx, 'DisplayName', 'finite difference');
plot(t, polyval(dp, t), 'DisplayName', 'polynomial');
legend show

figure('Name', 'Error')
hold on
plot(t, abs(dy_dt_approx - dy_dt_exact)/max(dy_dt_exact), 'DisplayName', 'finite difference');
plot(t, abs(polyval(dp, t) - dy_dt_exact)/max(dy_dt_exact), 'DisplayName', 'polynomial');
legend show
```

[image]
[image]

The first graph shows the derivatives itself and the second graph plots the relative errors made by both methods.

**Discussion**

One clearly sees that the curve fitting method gives better results than the finite differences, but it is ~100x slower. The curve fitting methods has a relative error of order `10^-5`. Note that the finite differences approach becomes better when your data is sampled more densely or you use a higher order scheme. The disadvantage of the curve fitting approach is that one has to choose a good polynomial order. Spline functions may be better suited in general.

A 10x faster sampled dataset, i.e. `t = 0:0.01:1;`, results in the following graphs:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Dear all, thank you for your messages and useful answers. Is it possible, to find an accurate numerical derivative using not polyder, but a spline interpolation?

Comment: For spline fitting, you can have a look at the matlab documentation for [`spline`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/spline.html) and [spline fitting](https://mathworks.com/help/curvefit/spline-fitting.html). [This post](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95194-how-do-i-find-the-derivative-of-a-spline-curve-in-matlab-7-9-r2009b) may be useful to calculate its derivative.

Comment: I meant to say, in the above example, in place of p = polyfit(t,y,5); dp = polyder(p), can one write p = spline(t,y,y), dp = polyder(p)? Will that calculate the derivatives accurately too? Spline avoids Runge's phenomenon, but I am not sure it can be used here.

Comment: You can use splines, but your syntax is not correct. You should check the manual.

Comment: I checked the manual, and now I am using a simple spline interpolation. t = 0:0.1:1;
time_new = [0:0.01:1];
y = sin(t);
dy_dt_exact = cos(t);
p = interp1(t,y,time_new,'spline');
dp = polyder(p);

But it does not seem like dp is a close match to cos(t). Also, how to make dp having the same length as dy_dt_exact vector? They have different lenghts.

Comment: @alex You should not use `interp1` as it does not return the internal spline representation. Also `polyder` is only for derivation of a polynomial function, so not for interpolated data. I think you should read my third link better or you may post a new question about spline interpolation and its (exact) derivatives as it falls outside the scope of this question (you did not mention splines in your question).

Comment: hi. I am not sure why interp1 should not be used quite frankly. I found in many applications it works quite well. For example, this command works fine.clc;clear;
t = [0:0.1:1];
t_new = [0:0.01:1];
y = sin(t);
dy_dt_exact = cos(t);
p = interp1(t,y,t_new,'spline');
plot(t,y,'o',t_new,p)
I will follow your advice and post a new question.

Comment: Because you want to calculate its derivative, which can be done exactly once you fitted a model to your data.