# spline interpolation and its (exact) derivatives

Tags: matlab, interpolation, derivative

Suppose I have the following data and commands:

```
clc;clear;
t = [0:0.1:1];
t_new = [0:0.01:1];
y = [1,2,1,3,2,2,4,5,6,1,0];
p = interp1(t,y,t_new,'spline');
plot(t,y,'o',t_new,p)
```

You can see they work quite fine, in the sense interpolating function matches the data points at the nodes fine. But my problem is, I need to compute the exact derivative of y (i.e., p function) w.r.t. time and plot it against the t vector. How can it be done? I shall not use diff commands, because I need to make sure the derivative function has the same length as t vector. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that this question is a follow up question of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44954893/non-symbolic-derivative-at-all-sample-points-including-boundary-points/44958969).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Method A: Using the derivative

This method calculates the actual derivative of the polynomial. If you have the curve fitting toolbox you can use:

```
% calculate the polynominal
pp = interp1(t,y,'spline','pp')
% take the first order derivative of it
pp_der=fnder(pp,1);
% evaluate the derivative at points t (or any other points you wish)
slopes=ppval(pp_der,t);
```

If you don't have the curve fitting toolbox you can replace the `fnder`line with:

```
% piece-wise polynomial
[breaks,coefs,l,k,d] = unmkpp(pp);
% get its derivative
pp_der = mkpp(breaks,repmat(k-1:-1:1,d*l,1).*coefs(:,1:k-1),d);
```

Source: [This mathworks question](https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95194-how-do-i-find-the-derivative-of-a-spline-curve-in-matlab-7-9-r2009b). *Thanks to  m7913d for linking it.*

**Appendix:**

Note that

```
p = interp1(t,y,t_new,'spline');
```

is a shortcut for

```
% get the polynomial 
pp = interp1(t,y,'spline','pp');
% get the height of the polynomial at query points t_new
p=ppval(pp,t_new);
```

To get the derivative we obviously need the polynomial and can't just work with the new interpolated points. To avoid interpolating the points twice which can take quite long for a lot of data, you should replace the shortcut with the longer version. So a fully working example that includes your code example would be:

```
t = [0:0.1:1];
t_new = [0:0.01:1];
y = [1,2,1,3,2,2,4,5,6,1,0];

% fit a polynomial 
pp = interp1(t,y,'spline','pp');
% get the height of the polynomial at query points t_new
p=ppval(pp,t_new);
% plot the new interpolated curve
plot(t,y,'o',t_new,p)

% piece-wise polynomial
[breaks,coefs,l,k,d] = unmkpp(pp);
% get its derivative
pp_der = mkpp(breaks,repmat(k-1:-1:1,d*l,1).*coefs(:,1:k-1),d);
% evaluate the derivative at points t (or any other points you wish)
slopes=ppval(pp_der,t);
```

#### Method B: Using finite differences

A derivative of a continuous function is at its base just the difference of f(x) to f(x+infinitesimal difference) divided by said infinitesimal difference.

In matlab, `eps` is the smallest difference possible with a double precision. Therefore after each `t_new` we add a second point which is `eps` larger and interpolate `y` for the new points. Then the difference between each point and it's +eps pair divided by eps gives the derivative.

The problem is that if we work with such small differences the precision of the output derivatives is severely limited, meaning it can only have integer values. Therefore we add values slightly larger than eps to allow for higher precisions.

```
% how many floating points the derivatives can have
precision = 10;
% add after each t_new a second point with +eps difference
t_eps=[t_new; t_new+eps*precision];
t_eps=t_eps(:).';
% interpolate with those points and get the differences between them
differences = diff(interp1(t,y,t_eps,'spline'));
% delete all differences wich are not between t_new and t_new + eps
differences(2:2:end)=[];
% get the derivatives of each point
slopes = differences./(eps*precision);
```

You can of course replace `t_new` with `t` (or any other time you want to get the differential of) if you want to get the derivatives at the old points.

This method is slightly inferior to method a) in your case, as it is slower and a bit less precise. But maybe it's useful to somebody else who is in a different situation.

Comment: I think using finite differences is not the most efficient/accurate method. As  you are using splines to interpolate the data, I think [this method](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/95194-how-do-i-find-the-derivative-of-a-spline-curve-in-matlab-7-9-r2009b) is better to calculate to exact derivative of the fitted spline.

Comment: @m7913d I fully agree! wasn't aware that that would work in this case. Do you want to write it as an answer? I'm going to delete this answer then.

Comment: You may do it if you want.

Comment: Thank you. I use the commands suggested, yet after the last command in the line I get an error. clc;clear;
t = [0:0.1:1];
t_new = [0:0.01:1];
y = [1,2,1,3,2,2,4,5,6,1,0];
pp = interp1(t,y,t_new,'spline');
plot(t,y,'o',t_new,pp);
[breaks,coefs,l,k,d] = unmkpp(pp);
Error using unmkpp (line 18)
The input array does not seem to describe a pp function.

Comment: @Alex You have to use `spline(t,y)`, not `interp1(t,y,t_new,'spline')`. The former returns the polynomial, while the latter gets the values at t_new. I edited the question and added the parts that are necessary for you.

Comment: Thank you. But what if I need to use interp1? For example, sometimes it is important to use the command p = interp1(t,y,t_new,'pchip'). How can the above method be used?

Comment: @Alex You can use the `'pp'` option. E.g. `pp = interp1(t,y,'pchip','pp')`

Comment: I just replaced one of my earlier commands with the one you have suggested, and now I am getting a plotting error if use the code: clc;clear; t = [0:0.001:0.01]; 
t_new = [0:0.00001:0.01]; 
y = [0.9999, 0.9998, 0.9997, 0.9996, 0.9995, 0.0005, 0.0004, 0.0003, 0.0002, 0.0001,0]; 
pp = interp1(t,y,'pchip','pp') 
plot(t,y,'o',t_new,pp)
when I used p = interp1(t,y,t_new,'pchip'); I had no such error.

Comment: sorry, what appendix? I just used this new command pp = interp1(t,y,'pchip','pp')

Comment: Moved the content to the appendix to the end of answer a). Just read it a second time now.

Comment: slightly modified based on your code. OK now? Slightly modified based on your code. OK now? t = [0:0.1:1];
t_new = [0:0.01:1];
y = [0,0.01,0.04,0.09,0.16,0.25,0.36,0.49,0.64,0.81,1];
% fit a polynomial 
pp = interp1(t,y,'pchip','pp');
% get the height of the polynomial at query points t_new
p=ppval(pp,t_new);
% piece-wise polynomial
[breaks,coefs,l,k,d] = unmkpp(pp);
% get its derivative
pp_der = mkpp(breaks,repmat(k-1:-1:1,d*l,1).*coefs(:,1:k-1),d);
% evaluate the derivative at points t (or any other points you wish)
slopes=ppval(pp_der,t);
plot(t,y,'o',t_new,p, t,slopes)

Comment: But why after plotting, I see that there is a small kink in the plot of the derivative at point 0.1? Should it not be a straight line?

Comment: Yeah, this seems correct. The kink is just due to your data -  maybe whatever process you were measuring has some start up time?

Comment: It is just a simple quadratic function y=x^2. The derivative should be 2*x. I am not sure why the method provides a kink for a simple function like this.

Comment: That has to do with the interpolation method. By using `spline` you get the expected slopes. But i'm not going to discuss interpolation methods here, that is a completely different topic (it was originally about derivatives). But you may want to read http://blogs.mathworks.com/cleve/2012/07/16/splines-and-pchips/